# Преобразование списка байтов в байт-строку

Tags: python, массивы, байты

Имеется массив значения байта (в диапазоне 0...255)

```py
[10,49,52,251,4,...]
```

необходимо преобразовать в последовательность

```py
b'/xa/x31/x34/xfb/x4...
```

Answer (score 3):

[Вот решение на англоязычном stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470398/convert-list-of-ascii-codes-to-string-byte-array-in-python)

Как по мне самый лучший вариант в Python 3 и старше:

```
>>> bytes([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t'
```